# JQuery month picker on month change/select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Using jQuery UIMonthPicker http://jsfiddle.net/kidsysco/JeZap/ and I'm having difficulty in trying an event on month select. There is no response on either onClose or onSelect function. Here is my code:

```
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$('#txtDate').MonthPicker({
        ShowIcon: false,
        MaxMonth: 0,
        MinMonth: -120,
        onSelect: function() {
            alert(j$("#txtDate").val());
        }
    });

    j$("#txtDate").keydown(false);
    j$("#txtDate").change(function(){
        alert(j$("#txtDate").val());
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs, you might want [OnAfterChooseMonth](https://github.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker#onafterchoosemonth)

```
j$('#txtDate').MonthPicker({ 
    ....
    OnAfterChooseMonth: function() { 
        alert($(this).val());
    } 
});
```

The `change` event will only fire when the input is changed by the user typing into it (and losing focus depending on control) - it doesn't fire when code changes the value.

---

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeZap/459/) (on the first 'default' input)

---

Update: to address the incorrect edit that was made to this answer and incase it happens again: I rolled back because the **question** uses `j$ = jQuery.noConflict();` and so `$()` might fail *in this context* and the `...` shows that there needs to be more inside the `MonthPicker` than just what's here. To the reviewers: don't forget to check the question when reviewing.